# Catel: Deserialize works for 1 unit test, fails for another

Tags: c#, unit-testing, serialization, catel

Using VS 2015.

I'm upgrading my apps from Catel 4.4.0 to 4.5.4.  Of course, there were numerous changes to Models using SavableModelBase.Load parameters, but I got those fixed and everything compiles with no error or warnings.

I ran my unit tests and I have 1 test that fails.  The test requires a delegate to load an XML data file which was previously serialized.  The delegate then retrieves a YearConstants instance from a collection by year.  The delegate is:

```
public static YearConstants GetYearConstantsByYearAndFileName(int year, string fileName)
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var constants = ConstantsData.Load(fs, SerializationMode.Xml, null);
            var results = constants.YearConstantsList.Where(x => x.Year == year).FirstOrDefault();
            if (results == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "YearConstants not found for [{0}] in file [{1}]", year, fileName));
            }

            return results;
        }
    }
```

When the unit test using this delegate is run, the "constants" var has a value, but doesn't contain any year data.  When I break on all CLR exceptions, I'm getting the following exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException occurred
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.XmlSerializationContextInfo' to type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.Binary.BinarySerializationContextInfo'.
  Source=Catel.Core
  StackTrace:
       at Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializerBase`1.Deserialize(Object model, ISerializationContextInfo serializationContext, ISerializationConfiguration configuration) in C:\CI_WS\Ws\97969\Source\Catel\src\Catel.Core\Catel.Core.Shared\Runtime\Serialization\SerializerBase.deserialization.cs:line 154
  InnerException:
```

I've added a unit test to just test loading the same file and it passes with no exceptions:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [DeploymentItem(@"TestData\GeorgiaConstants.xml")]
    public void ConstantsData_SerializationWithLiveDataTest()
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream("GeorgiaConstants.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var constants = ConstantsData.Load(fs, SerializationMode.Xml, null);
            Assert.IsNotNull(constants, "The constants data was not correctly loaded from 'GeorgiaConstants.xml' file.");
            Assert.AreEqual(5, constants.YearConstantsList.Count, "The expected number of year constants was not loaded from the 'GeorgiaConstants.xml' file.");

            // We should have year constants for 2016 for a while in the file.
            var yearConstants = constants.YearConstantsList.Where(x => x.Year == 2016).FirstOrDefault();
            Assert.IsNotNull(yearConstants, "The year constants for year = 2016 were not found in 'GeorgiaConstants.xml' file.");

            // We shouldn't be able to find year constants for a year this old.
            yearConstants = constants.YearConstantsList.Where(x => x.Year == 1999).FirstOrDefault();
            Assert.IsNull(yearConstants, "The year constants for year = 1999 were UNEXPECTEDLY found in 'GeorgiaConstants.xml' file.");
        }
    }
```

Both file streams show the same number of bytes read.  Also, the constants XML file contains a "created" date, "modified" date, and "created by" string which are being read correctly.  If I run the failing unit test by itself, it still fails so it doesn't appear to be a file sharing/locking issue.  It's just the ObservableCollection of year constants is being read correctly by the 2nd code, but not by the first.

I've run out of things to try.  Does anyone have a suggestion as to the cause for this or another approach I could use?

thanks,
randy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's mixing up the Xml and Binary serialization methods. Please create a ticket in the [official issue tracker](http://catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker) so this can be fixed.

Comment: I've created a ticket.  I'll see if I can create a small project which replicates the issue to attach to it, but there is so much code in the app, that might be difficult.